# How to install Node.js on a Raspberry Pi B+

Tags: node.js, raspberry-pi

I'm having trouble installing it on my Raspberry Pi B+.
I tried [this](https://nodejs.org/en/download/package-manager/#debian-and-ubuntu-based-linux-distributions) but it keeps saying

```
## You appear to be running on ARMv6 hardware. Unfortunately this is not currently supported by the NodeSource Linux distributions. Please use the 'linux-armv6l' binary tarballs available directly from nodejs.org for Node.js v4 and later.
```

and i can't find a proper tutorial. Please help

Comment: Did you follow the error instructions? You need to install one of the binaries built for this architecture.

Answer (score 0):

Find the appropriate download from here: https://nodejs.org/en/download/

Yours looks like: https://nodejs.org/dist/v8.9.4/node-v8.9.4-linux-armv6l.tar.xz

Comment: Is there a command or just run the install
And that's why i'm asking
i can't find the right download